# JavaFX update ObservableList with extractor that's used in UI from non-JavaFX thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, properties, observablelist

I have access to an `ObservableList<T>` that is updated(elements added, removed) from non-JavaFX thread, which I display in `ListView<T>`.

If the list is simply displayed in UI it throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;` so my solution was to create second list in UI thread and listen to changes and update the second list in UI thread:

```
ObservableList<Person> secondList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
secondList.addAll(originalList);
originalList.addListener((ListChangeListener<? super Person>)change-> {
    while(change.next()) {
        if (change.wasRemoved()) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> secondList.subList(change.getFrom(), change.getFrom() + change.getRemovedSize()).clear());
        }

        if (change.wasAdded()) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> secondList.addAll(change.getFrom(), change.getAddedSubList()));
        }
    }
});
ListView<Person> listViewPerson = new ListView<>(secondList);
```

This I believe should work fine(if it has any problems, please point them out, I'm ignoring permutation for question's simplicity).

However, the problem arises when the list has an extractor:

```
ObservableList<Person> secondList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(person -> new Observable[]{person.adultProperty()});
```

The change to adult property happens on non-javafx thread and obviously that will either throw the same exception or will result in some undefined UI behavior.

I've thought of 2 solutions for this problem:

1) creating UI equivalent classes of original classes and update its' properties in UI thread:

```
public PersonUI(Person person) {
    adult = new SimpleBooleanProperty(person.isAdult());
    person.adultProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        Platform.runLater(() -> this.adult.set(newValue));
    });
}
```

and in UI display `PersonUI` instead of `Person`.

Don't think it's necessary, but here's full code of this solution: https://pastebin.com/FYXrre6U

2) Pollute back-end code with `Platform.runLater()`

Are there any other solutions? If there are any problems with my current solutions please point them out.

Comment: The `ListChangeListener` has problems: Your listener always adds new elements to the back but new elements can be inserted anywhere in the list. Furthermore if you allow duplicates in the list: `removeAll` will remove every single occurance of the element. Also you completely ignore permutation changes.

Comment: maybe use the extrator on the original list and change its listener to propagate update events (or whatever the extractor fires, don't remember right now, will look later) on the fx thread

Comment: @fabian Updated the code according to your comment.

Comment: It seems to me a bit off that you change an `ObservableList` from a background thread, but it feels even more wrong to be modifying the state of a model from multiple threads. I can't think of a "rule-of-thumb" or else a "philosophical" argument why this shouldn't be done... but could you maybe explain the workflow that lead to this being the case?

Comment: why did you add the permutation? While it might be necessary in production code (really permutate the backing list?), it's clouding your problem here ... KISS - even or particularly in qa code :)

Comment: on a technical SO note: please move your complete example code into the question

Comment: I'd probably tend towards your second solution: managing the threading from the back-end. Note that you don't really need to explicitly include the `Platform.runLater(...)` in the backend code: you can abstract it out as a configurable `Executor` (after all, `Platform.runLater(...)` is just a mechanism for executing `Runnable`s.) Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79154/generic-gui-background-task-runner-java-8

Comment: @kleopatra I updated and removed permutation, however it might be OK to add it back for future readers to be able understand it's necessary in production? And as for link to complete code, I'm not sure it's really that helpful and I don't want to pollute the question with unnecessary code.

Comment: @James_D The application I'm working on right now is mostly only displaying the data model and doesn't really have a lot of actions from the side of UI, so I'm not sure the code you linked will help me. Maybe I just misunderstood, if so please correct me.

Comment: @sillyfly well it's just that the back-end is developed before front-end and it also feels wrong to change back-end code just to adapt to front-end "framework". Not sure what you mean by state of a model modified from multiple threads?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for SO conventions

Answer (score 1):

Option 3: implement a transformationList that propagates all changes onto the fx-thread. It's a bit of work front-up, but can be re-used.

An outline (not formally tested and incomplete!)

```
/**
 * A 1:1 transform of the sourceList that guarantees to fire change notification
 * on the fx-thread.
 * 
 * @author Jeanette Winzenburg, Berlin
 */
public class FXThreadTransformationList<E> extends TransformationList<E, E> {

    public FXThreadTransformationList(ObservableList<E> source) {
        super(source);
    }

    @Override
    protected void sourceChanged(Change<? extends E> c) {
        beginChange();
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                // tbd
            } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                update(c);
            } else if (c.wasReplaced()) {
                // tbd
            } else {
                addedOrRemoved(c);
            }
        }
        // commit on fx-thread
        endChangeOnFXThread();
    }

    public void endChangeOnFXThread() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> endChange());
    }

    private void addedOrRemoved(Change<? extends E> c) {
        if (c.wasRemoved()) {
            nextRemove(c.getFrom(), c.getRemoved());
        } else if (c.wasAdded()) {
            nextAdd(c.getFrom(), c.getTo());  
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("expected either removed or added, but was:" + c);
        }
    }

    private void update(Change<? extends E> c) {
        for (int pos = c.getFrom(); pos < c.getTo(); pos++) {
            nextUpdate(pos);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewIndex(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceIndex(int index) {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return getSource().get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return getSource().size();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(FXThreadTransformationList.class.getName());
}
```